# php email an entire page

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

I have a php page which shows an entire time schedule for a user in html table format.
this page is generated when the user is selected from a drop down and a search is run

Now, I would like the functionality for this entire page to be emailed to the user when a button is clicked

user's email address is stored in a mysql information table and all users have a primary user_id associated with them

I am looking for a script which allows a page to be emailed, along with some text content. the script will also retrieve the email address of the user from database

How can this be done?

**UPDATE: I FOUND AN EASY WAY, ON THE PHP PAGE WHERE THIS SCHEDULE IS SHOWN IN TABLE FORMAT, I POSTED A LINK TO ANOTHER PHP PAGE. 
WHEN CLICKED IT RETRIEVES THE SAME DATA FROM DATABASE, ALONG WITH EMAIL ADDRESS OF USER (BASED ON USER_ID STORED IN SESSION VARIABLE) AND EMAILS THE ENTIRE DATA IN PROPERLY FORMATTED HTML TABLE FORMAT TO THE USER.. HOPE THIS HELPS SOMEONE ELSE LOOKING FOR SIMILAR FUNCTIONALITY**

Comment: Google for "email php" and try to make it yourself. Then ask questions here with issues you may encounter.

Comment: i found an easy way, on the same page where this table is shown i put up a link to another php page which retrieves the same schedule from database along with user's email address based on user_id stored in session and emails it directly when the link is clicked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use file_get_contents() to make a request for the page you want, and then email it.

```
$url = "get_email_data.php?id=" . $user_id;
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$email_body = "This is some other text <br/>" . $data;

//DO EMAIL STUFF RIGHT HERE SENDING $email_body AS THE BODY OF THE MESSAGE
```

Comment: That is a very simplistic and security prone way to do this though. You would need to introduce security measures like tokens to ensure only the proper user can request that data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?    
$to = "m@maaking.com"; //GET THIS FROM DATABASE
$from = "m2@maaking.com"; 
$subject = "Hello! This is HTML email"; 

//begin of HTML message 
$message = <<<EOF 
<html> 
  <body bgcolor="#DCEEFC"> 
    <center> 
        <b>Looool!!! I am reciving HTML email......</b> <br> 
        <font color="red">HEllo Hpw are you....all other stuff</font> <br> 
        <a href="http://www.maaking.com/">* maaking.com</a> 
    </center>
```

**//PUT YOUR TABLE HERE**

```
      <br><brRegards<br>Rajat Singhal 
  </body> 
</html> 
EOF; 
   //end of message 
    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

    //options to send to cc+bcc 
    //$headers .= "Cc: [email]maa@p-i-s.cXom[/email]"; 
    //$headers .= "Bcc: [email]email@maaking.cXom[/email]"; 

            // now lets send the email. 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

echo "Message has been sent....!"; 
?>
```